# Gridster not working properly after adding "delete"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using gridster and have added delete function so that I can delete the box.
Now when I delete any one of the box, the alignment is distorted and there is a blank space left out. And also when I try to drag and drop the boxes to change their position, the boxes are overlapping.(Please refer image)

Every thing works fine if delete function is not applied.

I have created a `jsfiddle.net/NMF5n/5/`
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMF5n/5/)

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at Gridster website and demos `http://gridster.net/#demos`, I find a way to delete items:

```
gridster.remove_widget(... the item ...);
```

So using it in your sample:

```
$(".del_img").click(function(){
    gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());
});
```

Where gridster is:

```
var gridster = $(".bla").gridster({
    widget_margins: [10, 10],
    widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140],
    widget_selector : "div",
    resize: {
        enabled: true
    }
}).data('gridster');
```

See fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/NMF5n/7/